# Help Recover Windows Hibernation After Dual-Booting

Tags: dual-boot, hibernate

I dual-booted Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 as guided at:
[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported). For dual booting, I had to removed the hibernation file in windows using *powercfg.exe -h off* as mentioned in the guide so I can no more hibernate Windows 8.1.

Now, I need to hibernate windows 8.1 without losing the dualboot.

1.Is there any windows 8.1 software that help recreate hibernation file?

Or

2.. Any other way I can hibernate windows 8.1?